# how to fix " [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '�' " error in odbc?

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to connect to a sql server database with php using odbc, it was working fine and then I changed the sql query and I got this error:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '�'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in ...

I tried to go back to the initial query that was working but I got the same error.

I checked the syntax I couldn't find anything and both queries work fine when executed on sql server management studio.

```
$dsn2 = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$servername2;Database=$dbname";

$conn2 = odbc_connect( $dsn2 , $username2 ,  $password2);

$sql = "SELECT top(1) Ticket.RFC_NUMBER AS [T-N° de ticket]
            ,Catalog_.[TITLE_FR] AS [T-CI]
            ,Group_.[GROUP_FR] AS [A-Groupe_Intervenant]

            FROM [EVO_DATA50004].[50004].[SD_REQUEST] as Ticket
            inner join [EVO_DATA50004].[50004].[AM_ACTION] as Action_ WITH (NOLOCK) on Ticket.[REQUEST_ID] = Action_.[REQUEST_ID]
            inner join [EVO_DATA50004].[50004].[SD_CATALOG] as Catalog_ WITH (NOLOCK) on   Ticket.[SD_CATALOG_ID] = Catalog_.[SD_CATALOG_ID]
            inner join [EVO_DATA50004].[50004].[AM_GROUP] as Group_ WITH (NOLOCK) on Action_.[GROUP_ID] = Group_.group_ID
            left outer join [EVO_DATA50004].[50004].AM_EMPLOYEE AS Employee_ WITH (NOLOCK) ON Action_.DONE_BY_ID = Employee_.EMPLOYEE_ID 

            WHERE  Ticket.RFC_NUMBER like 'I%'
            AND    Action_.END_DATE_UT is null
            AND    Action_.STATUS_ID_ON_CREATE is not null
            AND    Action_.STATUS_ID_ON_CREATE in('12')
            And    Employee_.[LAST_NAME] is null
            AND    Action_.[group_id] in(42)";

$result = odbc_exec($conn2 , $sql);
```

Comment: `T-N°` is that symbol allowed as a column name in SQLServer

Comment: I have to ask, does your object really have the character `°` in it? Also, what with the (ab)use of `WITH (NOLOCK)`? What is the reason for putting it everywhere? You know the implications of using their hint, right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well the column exists I don't know if it's allowed.

Comment: @RiggsFolly a SQL Server object name can have any character (except `CHAR(0)`. The datatype used to store the values is `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`. That doesn't, however, mean you *should* use those characters. Honsestly, I would still to Alphanumerical characters, and *if needs must) underscores (`_`). Certainly not a `°` character, which means you have to know the ASCII/Unicode value to even type it. >_<

Comment: @Larnu I don't have access to the database they gave me the queries I only implement them so I can work with on my project.

Comment: The `�` character means there is an encoding problem. Most likely because of that `°` character (as nothing else looks like it'll cause an encode issue). Honestly the real solution here is rename that column to something that doesn't use a special character (and get rid of those `WITH (NOLOCK)` hints, as they are clearly being misused).

Comment: @Larnu I got rid of ° charcter and it worked without renaming the column and It gave the same result with/without the °, I don't get it..

Comment: if `[T-N de ticket]` worked, that means that column doesn't have the character in it's name. Simple as that.

Comment: @Larnu it actually worked in sql server with both [T-N de ticket] and [T-N° de ticket] but in php it still gives the error even when removing °.

Comment: Are you sure that this field is the reason for your error? I'm not able to reproduce this error. It works for me with `$dsn = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server='.$sql_server.';Database='.$sql_database.';client_charset=UTF-8;'` and this simple statement `$sql = "SELECT 'ABC' AS [T-N° de ticket]; "`. I'm using PHP 7.1.2 and of course, PHP file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @Zhorov I'm actually not sure about the reason for this error. I tried everything it only works without error when I minimize it like this:  $sql = "SELECT top(1) Ticket.RFC_NUMBER AS [T-N° de ticket] FROM [EVO_DATA50004].[50004].[SD_REQUEST] as Ticket WHERE  Ticket.RFC_NUMBER like 'I%' "